# Mobile browser ignoring markup and script areas (Webkit, Android)

Tags: android, html, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm working on web app (a C# MVC app) in which the view engine renders a different view page when it detects a mobile browser. In particular I'm targeting the Android web kit browser (on Froyo). Oddly the page *does* render correctly on the iPhone.

The problem is that when I test locally on the emulator it renders fine, and if I use Chrome on the desktop it renders fine... however, when I test on an actual phone (Nexus 1 and MyTouch) the markup is ignored and all text nodes are rendered as text.  This happens using the HTML5 DOCTYPE  (even using the simplest markup).  If I insert an xmlns attribute into the  tag (xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml") it will pay attention to the markup, but this come with it's own set of problems (most specifically it seems not to work with JQuery Moblie) and I'd much prefer to omit the namespace.

Also, just as a shot in the dark I explicitly set the content type to text/html to see if that would help, but no luck.  I'm sure you all figured it out when I said I was writing this in C#, but the web server is IIS.

Even this simple markup doesn't work:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>html5 test for android</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>h1 markup</h1>
<h2>h2 markup</h2>

<p>this is a paragraph of text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm a newb in the mobile web dev arena - so I'm hoping this is such a simple and brainless issue it's something that everyone but me knows (which is why I'm not having any luck finding any direction on the web).

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: A sample http response text would be useful (pure text of the page source and http headers.)

Comment: Take a look at encoding - you should use utf8 nowadays.

Comment: I've specifically set the content type to "text/html" and the encoding to UTF-8 in the server response - but that hasn't made a difference.  With the markup I've included in the post above the browser outputs a single line of plain text which displays all of the included text (no markup) in the browser.  The HTML returned from the server is identical to what is in the post.  I don't know a good way to view the http headers returned to the android browser (any suggestions?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the use of the mobile.browser file (from CodePlex).  The file was indicating the server that the preferred mime type for my android browser was application/xhtml+xml rather than text/html.  Setting the content type in the action method of the controller did not correct the problem.  We ended up explicitly setting the content type in the page directive.  We will probably revisit this solution to determine if the mobile.browser file is something we'll continue to use.

Answer (score 0):

Android web browsers should be able to make use of HTML5.  The above code is just plain old HTML.  You should put the HTML5 doctype in there as follows:

If that still doesn't work, I think you have some issues with the browser capability sniffing issue with ASP.NET.  As for jQuery, if the browser can support HTML5, you might as well try to use the full blown jQuery.  I know it works with the Android phone because I've tested it out on the Android simulator.  Try looking into the ASP.NET browser capabilities first because it might have downgraded the browser capabilities of the Android webkit browser if ASP.NET cannot define what kind of browser and/or device it is dealing with.  Other than that, you can try and write a non-server page (a plain HTML file) and see if that page renders correctly.  Also, try using the regular jQuery 1.4.x rather than the mobile version.

Comment: FWIW, JQuery mobile requires the regular JQuery library and I have included the <!DOCTYPE html> tag (though I left it out of the example there).  As I mentioned in the post, the page(s) render correctly in the emulator, just not on the actual phone.  The pages are written in ASP.NET MVC so, down-leveling of controls is probably not the problem (besides, using the mark up I included in the post is about as simple as it could get).  I will try rendering a flat html page next.

Comment: As it happens.... I'd like a little salt (and maybe some salsa) on the crow I'm about to consume.   It turns out that, though not the browser capabilites functionality, it was a similar issue (using the mobile.browser file as per a post by Hanselmann) that caused the issue.  Although I was explicitly setting the content type, it turned out that the server was overwriting my change).  The file specified that the preferred mime type was application/xhtml + xml rather than text/html. Thanks for your help.